# How do you share the wifi connection of a raspberry pi over ethernet

Tags: networking, wifi

Update: after removing "pihole" software which was controlling dns, computer is working. I have to check if the script from Mr. Agarwal works now.

I followed instructions from [elsewhere on this site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/50073/revisions) to share the wifi connection of a raspberry pi to the ethernet port. Steps included downloading a script for Raspbian Stretch and running the script.
I have been unable to get this to work using the script referenced on that post for download. My computer gets an IP address on the correct subnet (`192.168.2.100`) but still no internet access, can't ping google or `192.168.1.1`. In fact, I couldn't even ping `192.168.2.1` for some reason.
I tried this using two different ethernet cables and a crossover cable, on two different computers using manjaro Linux and mint.

Does anybody have an updated method for sharing a wifi internet connection to ethernet on the raspberry pi?

Note that I followed instructions left by Mr. Agarwal, though the `lxsession` directory didn't exist on my pi. I am using `lxde` too. I made the file in the directory specified, `nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Comment: It is far from clear what you did. The link points to an edit and appears to be for an obsolete OS

Comment: PS try writing in paragraphs

Comment: 1) you need to setup your iptables firewall to forward the traffic properly https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222065/243440 2) also you need to enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` 3) you need to install a dhcp-server `dnsmasq` for example